# How to insert a photo on the right of the tabular in CV?

Tags: tables, graphics, cv

I am trying to make a CV with a photo on the right.

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{l}r}
    \large\textsc{Name:} &\large\bf{Dale Cooper} & \\
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} & April 19 1954 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & Maple Ave. 15, 92391 Twin Peaks, USA \\
    \textsc{Tel:}     & +154141165162141\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:lp@gmail.com}{lp@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I need to put the photo like this.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{l}r}
    \large\textsc{Name:} &\large\bf{Dale Cooper} & \\
    \textsc{Date of Birth:} & April 19 1954 \\
    \textsc{Address:}   & Maple Ave. 15,\\
    & 92391 Twin Peaks, USA \\
    \textsc{Tel:}     & +154141165162141\\
    \textsc{email:}     & \href{mailto:lp@gmail.com}{lp@gmail.com}
\end{tabular} 
\end {minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is defined 5 columns for table and than use only 2?

Comment: @Zarko No idea, I just copied it from the original code.

Comment: Wouldn't be more appropiate \textbf{ ... } instead of \bf{ ... }?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `\raisebox`and a good photo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{array,  graphicx} %
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{\scshape}l*{3}{l}r}
  \large Name: & \large\textbf{Pepé le Pew} & \qquad\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+1.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pepe-le-pew1}} \\
  Date of Birth:  & January 6   1945\\
  Address:    & Warner Blvd 4000, CA 9915522 Burbank, USA \\
  Tel:      & +154141165162141\\
  email:      & \href{mailto:skinky@LooneyTunes.com}{skinky@LooneyTunes.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]